# Open Xava: How to get the parameter from the URL in Open Xava?

Tags: url, getparameter, openxava

I'm developing a web application (says it's ExtApp, in Open Xava), where it will be called from another Application's Action Menu (says it's InApp).

So when user click on the "Action Menu" button in InApp, it will launch the ExtApp, and i can see the URL like http://ExtApp:8080/Action/m/Action?**value1=2485436**&**value2=0000019956**&**value2=xxxx**
How do i get the value in Open Xava from the parameter in the URL?
value1=
value2=
value3=

Answer (score 0):

From an action you can write:

```
public void execute() throws Exception {
    String value1 = getRequest().getParameter("value1");
    ...
}
```